# How to define the Malach Panav from the book of Isaiah?

Tags: commentaries, malach-angel, isaiah-yeshaya-the-book

In Yeshayahu 63:9 there’s a mention of a ‘malach panav (מַלְאַךְ פָּנָיו)’, why is this malach refered to in this kind of way; why this specific entitlement; what does the combination of the words malach and panav learn us; what does the word panav learn us in relation to this malach?

And is this malach the same malach as the one being called ‘malach YHVH’, or the one being called ‘Malach Elohim’, or are all these distinct entities?

Answer (score 1):

[Chabad](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15994#v=9&showrashi=true) translates פָּנָיו֙ as *His presence*. That is, the malach who his specifically serving Hashem directly. It is used to show that this is a powerful and prestigious malach rather than one created for a simple task. as Rashi says on that pasuk.

> **He did not trouble [them]:** He did not trouble them according to their
>   deeds, that they deserved to suffer, for the angel of His
>   presencei.e., Michael the prince of the Presence, of those who
>   minister before Him saved them always as an agent of the Omnipresent.